# How to build an installer for a IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, installation

I made a WCF service and manually copied it to a directory with the correct permissions on a Windows 2008 box with a correctly configured IIS 7.0. It works ;-)

Can I find somewhere how to perform these tasks with a regular installer (.msi) file? Or should I not want this to be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is maybe too late, but if you use Visual Studio 2015 and Installshield 2015 it is really very simple to accomplish.

- Add a setup project
- Go to step 3: Configure the Target System
- Go to Internet Information Services and in the left panel you can add Web Sites and then Virtual Directories or Applications as you need
- Then you can select the .NET version, default document, content source among other settings

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can publish services in the same way you would deploy web content. Check this [MSDN link - Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx)